# Magento Apache Mod Rewrite URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a refer a friend module that gives people a long referral url

I want to shorten it to make it easier for people to type, but can figure out how to get it done in .htaccess

Below is the rewrite section of my .htaccess

I want to redirect

/ap/*** to /awardpoints/index/goReferral/referrer/**  (** is the customers id)

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^ap/([0-9]+)$ /awardpoints/index/goReferral/referrer/$1 [R]
```

but it doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]


############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is your RewriteBase? Root directory of your domain or something else?

Answer (score 0):

you can use magento internal url rewrite management to achieve this or you can try this

```
RewriteRule ^ap/([^/\.]+)/?$ /awardpoints/index/goReferral/referrer/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

following is (modified to your urls) copy & paste from http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

> ^ap/ Sees whether the requested page starts with page/. If it doesn’t,
>   this rule will be ignored.
>
> ([^/.]+) Here, the enclosing brackets signify that anything that is
>   matched will be remembered by the RewriteRule. Inside the brackets, it
>   says “I’d like one or more characters that aren’t a forward slash or a
>   period, please”. Whatever is found here will be captured and
>   remembered.
>
> /?$ Makes sure that the only thing that is found after what was just
>   matched is a possible forward slash, and nothing else. If anything
>   else is found, then this RewriteRule will be ignored.
>
> /awardpoints/index/goReferral/referrer/ The actual page which will be loaded by Apache. $1
>   is magically replaced with the text which was captured previously.
>
> [L] Tells Apache to not process any more RewriteRules if this one was
>   successful.

Comment: Just can't it get to work, I keep getting a 404, you say that this is possible to do via magento's rewrites?  Possible without having to make every one myself?

Comment: I managed to get it working with:


RewriteRule ^ap/([^/\.]+)$ http://www.mydomain.com/awardpoints/index/goReferral/referrer/$1 [L]

But all css/js fails to load